# Angular JSON data to create more form fields and capture data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

### Problem

I have a set of JSON data. I am displaying it on the screen to collect checkboxes and benefit limit figures for each item. The display works, but I'm unable to capture this info, even after assigning it to ng-model.

### My JSON Array

```
{
    "Mental health and substance use disorder services, including behavioral health treatment": [
        "Benefits for treating alcoholism & drug dependency",
        "Benefits for mental health services",
        "Coverage for autism spectrum disorders up to age 5"
    ],
    "Pediatric services, including oral and vision care": [
        "Preventive care - physician svcs",
        "Immunizations",
        "1 routine eye exam per year, to age 19",
        "Routine hearing exams, to age 19",
        "Dental - diagnostic & preventive",
        "Dental - basic",
        "Dental - major",
        "Metabolic formula & low protein food for inborn errors of metabolism",
        "Hearing aids to age 18",
        "Amino acid-based elemental infant formula, up to age 2",
        "Children's early intervention services, up to age 36 months"
    ],
    "Prescription drugs": [
        "Retail",
        "Mail service (home delivery)",
        "Off-label use for cancer & HIV/AIDS",
        "Contraceptives",
        "Home infusion therapy"
    ],
    "Maternity and newborn care": [
        "Pre- & postnatal care",
        "Delivery & inpatient maternity services",
        "Newborn child coverage",
        "Lamaze"
    ],
    "Emergency services": [
        "Emergency room care",
        "Ambulance service",
        "Urgent care centers/facilities"
    ],
    "Laboratory services": [
        "Lab tests & X-ray services",
        "Imaging/diagnostics (e.g.,  MRI, CT scan, PET scan"
    ],
    "Preventive and wellness services and chronic disease management": [
        "Preventive care",
        "Colorectal cancer screening",
        "Screening mammography",
        "Foot care",
        "Eye care & 1 routine eye exam per 2 yrs, unless over 65 or diabetic",
        "Audiology/hearing tests",
        "Nutritional counseling",
        "Smoking cessation program",
        "Allergy testing & injections",
        "Family planning",
        "Diabetes - medically necessary equip. & supplies; education",
        "Screening Pap tests",
        "Annual gynecological exam",
        "Annual prostrate cancer screening for men 50-72 yrs."
    ],
    "Others": [
        "Acupuncture",
        "Infertility treatment services",
        "TMJ services",
        "Biofeedback",
        "Funeral Expenses",
        "Bed ridden allowances"
    ],
    "Rehabilitative and habilitative services and devices": [
        "Physical, speech & occupational therapy",
        "Cardiac rehabilitation",
        "Pulmonary rehabilitation",
        "Durable medical equipment",
        "Prosthetics - arm or leg",
        "Skilled nursing & rehab"
    ],
    "Hospitalization - inpatient": [
        "Inpatient medical and surgical care",
        "Bariatric surgery",
        "Organ & tissue transplants",
        "Chemotherapy services",
        "Radiation therapy",
        "Anesthesia",
        "Breast reconstruction",
        "Breast reduction, symptomatic varicose vein surgery"
    ],
    "Ambulatory patient services": [
        "Primary care to treat illness/injury",
        "Specialist visits",
        "Outpatient surgery",
        "Chiropractic (therapeutic, adjustive, manipulative)",
        "Chemotherapy services",
        "Radiation therapy",
        "Anesthesia",
        "Walk-in center services",
        "Home health care",
        "AIDS/HIV parity",
        "Access to clinical trials",
        "Hospice",
        "Genetic evaluation & counseling"
    ]
}
```

### Display screen shot

This is how I display it on the page adding input fields to capture more details of the values that I then need to send back to the database

[image: json display]

Here is the controller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qI79.png)

Here is the template code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14NHU.png)

Comment: Can you post the controller code and the template? Better yet, can you make an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm curious to see how you declared the ng-model in html, do you mind posting it?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the template and controller as well